# Crear tabla y guardar datos en MemoryCache

Tags: c#

Estoy tratando de almacenar datos obtenidos de una db en cache, para no tener que consultar la tabla en X timepo. Leyendo encontre MemoryCache, que podría servirme para el proposito. Entonces mi idea era usar un DataTable con dos columnas de enteros, rellenarlas con los datos de la db si el DataTable es nulo y guardarlo en cache, o unicamente obtenerme el DataTable desde el cache si este no es nulo.

Entonces lo que tengo por el momento:

```
//3- Creo DataTable dtCliente y le agrego dos columnas
        DataTable dtCliente = new DataTable("Clientes");
        DataColumn nombres = dtCliente.Columns.Add("Nombre", typeof(string));
        DataColumn apellido = dtCliente.Columns.Add("Apellido", typeof(string));
        nombres.AllowDBNull = true;
        apellido.AllowDBNull = true;
```

Y aca deberia revisar si dtCliente es null, entonces pensaba algo asi pero me trabe porque no entiendo muy bien lo de cache:

```
//4- dtCliente es null? Si -> Cache es null? Si -> le pego a la db y relleno cache | No -> obtengo los datos en cache
        if (dtCliente == null)
        {

        }
```

Alguna sugerencia de como seguir? Gracias.

Comment: ¿Estás usando algún tipo de inyección de dependencias (Autofac, Ninject, ...)?

Comment: No, no estoy usando inyeccion de dependencias.

Comment: estas trabajando con proyecto web, escritorio, o mobile?

Answer (score 0):

Para el que necesite esto, lo solucione de esta forma:

```
public void CachearTabla()
    {
        //CREO UN DATATABLE CON LAS COLUMNAS QUE NECESITO
        DataTable cliente = new DataTable("ClienteDT");
        DataColumn nombre = cliente.Columns.Add("Nombre", typeof(String));
        DataColumn apellido = cliente.Columns.Add("Apellido", typeof(String));

        //INSTANCIO EL OBJECTCACHE QUE SIRVE PARA CACHEAR INFO
        //Reviso si el cache con la key usada tiene algo, sino le pego a la db y me obtengo lo que quiero
        ObjectCache cache = MemoryCache.Default;
        List<Cliente> listaClientes = new List<Cliente>();
        if (cache.Contains(keyCache))
            cliente = (DataTable)cache.Get(keyCache);
        else
        {
            using (var dc = new DBCliente())
            {
                listaClientes = dc.Cliente
                    .Select(x => new Cliente
                    {
                        Nombre = x.Nombre,
                        Apellido = x.Apellido
                    })
                    .ToList();
                foreach (var fila in listaClientes)
                {
                    DataRow newRow = cliente.NewRow();
                    newRow["Nombre"] = fila.Nombre;
                    newRow["Apellido"] = fila.Apellido;
                    cliente.Rows.Add(newRow);
                }
                CacheItemPolicy cacheItemPolicy = new CacheItemPolicy();
                cacheItemPolicy.AbsoluteExpiration = DateTime.Now.AddHours(1);
                cache.Add(keyCache, listaClientes, cacheItemPolicy);
            }
        }
    }

    private const string keyCache = "keyCache";
```